# Minimal normal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group with a proper non trivial normal subgroup $N$. Suppose that $N$ is solvable. Is it possible to find a normal abelian $p$-group $K$$\vartriangleleft$ $G$ (for some $p$ prime divisor of |$G$|)? How can I do?
Every kind of suggestion is appreciated. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Thannk you very much for the help @Nicky Hekster ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal normal subgroup of a finite solvable group $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two of these (i.e. for the same fixed prime $p$), then by minimality $N_1 \cap N_2 = 1$, so $[N_1,N_2]=1$. Hence any two of them commute, and the subgroup $K$ of $N$ generated by *all* minimal normal $p$-subgroups of $N$ is itself elementary abelian, and it is characteristic. So $K$ char $N$ and $N \unlhd G$, hence $K \unlhd G$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nicky !! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome! Was a bit more subtle than my hint suggested.

Comment: Excuse me @Nicky , I've another (stupid) question...is it true that $K$ is self centralizing in $N$?

Comment: What kind of conditions do I need?

Comment: This is a good question. Of course $K \subseteq C_N(K)$. Let me think about equality here.

Comment: thank you again, you're very kind

Comment: $K$ does not have to be self-centralizing: let $G$ be a group, $p$ the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ and assume $N \unlhd G$, $|N|=p$. Then as above $K=N \subseteq Z(G)$, whence $C_G(K)=G$. Abelian example: $G=C_p \times C_q$, $p,q$ primes, $p \lt q$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54715/discussion-between-nicky-hekster-and-sibilla).

Answer (score 2):

Look at $N$.

Consider its derived series, and smallest member, say $N^{(k)}\neq 1$ (but $N^{(k+1)}=1$).

Then $N^{(k)}$ is abelian (its derived subgroup is $1$).

Consider Sylow-$p$ subgroup $P$ of $N^{(k)}$ (for $p$ dividing $|N^{(k)}|$); it is unique, so characteristic in $N^{(k)}$.

So we have following chain of subgroups 
$$1 < P < N^{(k)} < N < G.$$
($P$ char in $N^{(k)}$) and ($N^{(k)}$ char in $N$) implies ($P$ char in $N$).

($P$ char in $N$) and ($N$ normal in $G$) implies $P$ is normal in $G$. **q.e.d.**

---

needless to say: ($H$ char $K$) means $H$ is characteristic in $K$.